# Angular.js ng-repeat unique identifier

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-repeat on a `<tr>` tag to populate the `<td>` tags with data pulled from mysql and converted into Json. This works just fine. However, one of the `<td>` tags that I'm using contains a button.

What I would like to do, is have each of these buttons identified somehow in the DOM, so that I can target then with specific requests.

Example: Page loads, ng-repeat repeats a button 4 times. Each of these buttons would have an ng-click attached to it. I want each of them to open and filter different information in a json file.

Am I correct in assuming that ng-repeat would simply open the same item for each button, and how would I go about making them seperate? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this on the front-end:

```
<button ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" ng-click="someFunction($index)" >Something happens</button>
```

Then in your controller:

```
$scope.someFunction = function (index) {
    if (index === 1):
        // etc.
    else...
        // Or use switch, whichever works for you.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create the specific function on each item in the array.

```
<button ng-repeat="button in buttons" ng-click="button.functionName()">{{button.name}}</function>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's $index for that. It's a very good habit to take for any of your ng-repeat. Also don't forget bind-once if your buttons UI isn't subject to modifications once the DOM has loaded.

```
 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="page in pages">
        <a ng-class="{ testClass: $index == pageNumber }" ng-click="setPageNumber($index)">{{ page }} - index is : {{$index}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bonatoc/4z1t4gsm/3/

Also you could do (using bind-once):

```
<button 
ng-repeat="button in ::buttons track by $index" 
id="button_{{$index}}" 
class="{{button['css_class']}}"
```

...given your buttons were a JSON object as well (beware, ng-repeat likes arrays, not objects. Arrays of objects are fine):

```
 $scope.buttons = [
   0: {
        'css_class': someClass,
        'functionToTrigger': function(...

// ...
```

Comment: The buttons are not a json object, they are just in the same <tr> as json data. The buttons are just blank bootstrap buttons.

Comment: I hear you. I just wanted to point out a possibility. When you do a ng-repeat, you're basically doing the equivalent of php's mysql_fetch_array, so you can pass virtually any value that comes to mind to the DOM element itself, in this case <button>.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at angular-material, which is IMHO better than Bootstrap. But if Bootstrap is your thing, you also have UI-Bootstrap (angular js port).